# Can the Aldiko reader show pdf files in it's catalog screen which are not present in the ebook folder?

Tags: ebook-reader, ebooks, aldiko

I have the following situation :

1. I purchased an Android pdf book which was downloaded on my PC
2. I used **Dropbox** to transfer it onto my Android device (*Archos 101*)
3. When clicking the downloaded book in the Dropbox Android application , the Aldiko read was launched, ready for my to read my book.
4. However, this **book was not present in the Aldiko book case view** when I later on started Aldiko again

*Hence my question:* **is it possible to let Aldiko list books which are not present in the eBook folder ?**

I can't move the pdf into eBook, because Dropbox will download it happily again, when it doesn't find it.

I don't want to have duplicates ( the book is rather large , but even when it wasn't , I don't like the idea of having exact files in multiple locations ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible workaround: Turn the `ebook` folder into a symlink to the `dropbox` folder.  Or if subfolders word, create a `dropbox` symlink inside `ebook`.

Comment: Matthew Read: You saw this coming, no ? How do you create a symlink ?

Comment: @Edelcom `ln -s /sdcard/dropbox /sdcard/ebook` creates ebook and makes it point to dropbox, assuming those are the correct paths.  Depending on your phone, you might need busybox to do that (and thus run `busybox ln` instead of just `ln`).  More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)#Symbolic_link_creation_and_deletion

Comment: on Android I'm just a new user, nothing more, but how do you enter such commands ? Is there a command prompt equivalent ? And do you need to be rooted to do this ? Thanks for you help.

Comment: Never mind: searched for terminal emulator in Android market and installed a program called (ahem) 'terminal emulator'. I have to brush up on my Linux/unix commands ...

Comment: initial test did not work ... will try again to make sure I had the correct folders.